# Frequently stopping Appication Pool [IIS with Wordpress]

Tags: wordpress, iis

If I modify something in the admin panel of the WordPress, the Application Pool stops. Every time it stops, I need to start the application pool manually from SolidCP panel.

I checked the logs, but I can't find any problems, just warnings.

I attached the IIS and also the WordPress logs:
 - [IIS Log](https://justpaste.it/u_ex191129)
 - [WordPress Log](https://justpaste.it/wp-debug)
 - ScreenShot:[image: Screenshot]

What could be the problem and how can I resolve it?

Thanks advanced,
Steve

Comment: What PHP version you currently running with?

Comment: I'm running Wordpress version 5.3, PHP version: 7.1.29 on a shared hosting.

Comment: In solidCP is selected 7.1.29, but I have newer versions too, like: 7.2.18 and 7.3.5.

Comment: I suggest you could also check the event viewer's logs to find out the reason about why your application pool stopped.